# Start a game loop with button push

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-button

I have created an activity PlayActivity that starts a new thread and a game loop. When I have this class as my launcher activity (MainActivity) it works perfectly. But I obviously do not want my app to start with the game loop! In my MainActivity I have different tabs as fragments, in my Home tab, I have a button. I want the game to start with the button clicked. Here is my PlayActivity:

```
public class PLayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN );
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH = dm.widthPixels;
        Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT = dm.heightPixels;

        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("test 3.xml");
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            setContentView(new PlayPanel(this, is));
        } catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home, null);
        basic = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.basic);
        intermediate = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById((R.id.intermidiate));

        basic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg) {

                // Start NewActivity.class
                Intent basicIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PLayActivity.class);
                startActivity(basicIntent);
            }
        });
```

Home.java:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {

    Button basic;
    Button intermediate;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Basic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/basic"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Intermidiate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/intermidiate"
        android:layout_below="@+id/basic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Advanced"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/advanced"
        android:layout_below="@+id/intermidiate"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click the button nothing happens! What should I do?

Comment: First of all try to add a breakpoint to your OnClickListener and check if it reached

Comment: I am not sure how to do that! How can I check that? appreciate your help

Comment: Well, I propose your to read this article about debugging in Android Studio - https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html